# half sync and half async pattern in operating system

Tags: architecture, operating-system

I am reading about half sync/half async pattern at following link.

http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/PLoP-95.pdf

http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/HS-HA.pdf

> It is mentioned in section 8.2 Identify short duration tasks and
>   implement them using asynchronous I/O.
>
> Implement these short-durationtasks using a reactive, passive object
>   model. Passive objects borrow their thread of control from elsewhere
>   (such as the caller or a separate interrupt stack). Therefore, these
>   tasks must use asynchronous I/O since they cannot block for long
>   periods of time. The primary motivation for not blocking is to ensure
>   adequate response time for other system tasks.

My question is

1. What does author mean by borrow thread from seperate interrupt stack above statment?

> Need for programming simplicity: Programming an asynchronous I/O model
>   can be complex because input and output operations are triggered by
>   interrupts. Asynchrony can cause subtle timing problems and race
>   conditions when the current thread of control is preempted by an
>   interrupt handler. Moreover, interrupt-driven programs require extra
>   data structures in addition to the run-time stack.

1. What does author mean by aysnc causes subtle timing problems  (request example here)?
2. Why interrupt driven programs requires extra data structure in addition to the run-time stack.
3. In general author is mentioning signals or interrupts as async and multi-threads , multi processes as sync? Why?

I am new to aysnc concepts so need your help here.

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

1. The operating system could be coded to use one thread to read a packet from the network, and another thread to process the packet.  However, when that is inefficient, then the same thread is used to both read and process the packet.  If you think of the thread as "belonging" to the code in the operating system that reads packets, then in a sense it is "borrowed" by the code that processes the packets.  Even if the thread priority or privileges change during the operation of the thread, it is still the same thread.

   Also, if the cost of creating and destroying a thread is a concern, a group of threads can be preallocated as a thread pool. Threads can be "borrowed" from this pool and subsequently returned.
2. Asynchronous processing is prone to race conditions, so it is more challenging to program than synchronous processing.